# Where did the class org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory go in Hibernate 5?

Tags: hibernate, migration

I am currently working on a project to upgrade from Hibernate 3.x to 5.x. Right now one of the properties in the hibernate configuration xml is as follows :

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
```

In Hibernate 5, this particular class defined above as well as the package **org.hibernate.transaction** does not seem to exist. This class is available in version 3.x however (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transaction/JDBCTransactionFactory.html).
No such class per the Hibernate 5 api docs(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/)

Did Hibernate 5 deprecate this particular package along with all of it's contained classes ? I checked in all the required Hibernate 5 jars but am unable to find this class **org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory** anywhere. What could be a suitable replacement for this class in Hibernate 5 configuration ?

I've had limited success with google searches so any answers would be appreciated !

Comment: Same situation for me - trying to upgrade from 3.3 to 5.2.9.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay so upon further research, I found that the Transaction SPI in Hibernate 5 underwent a major change !

The corresponding property should be :

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl</property>
```

or use the short name like this :

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jdbc</property>
```

From https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#transactions

> The transaction SPI underwent a major redesign as part of 5.0 as well. From a user perspective this generally only comes into view in terms of configuration. Previously applications would work with the different backend transaction stratagies directly via the org.hibernate.Transaction API. In 5.0 a level of indirection has been added here. The API implementation of org.hibernate.Transaction is always the same now. On the backend, the org.hibernate.Transaction impl talks to a org.hibernate.resource.transaction.TransactionCoordinator which represents the "transactional context" for a given Session according to the backend transaction strategy. Users generally do not need to care about the distinction.
>
> The change is noted here because it might affect your bootstrap configuration. Whereas previously applications would specify hibernate.transaction.factory_class and refer to a org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory FQN, **with 5.0 the new contract is org.hibernate.resource.transaction.TransactionCoordinatorBuilder and is specified using the hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class setting**. See org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.TRANSACTION_COORDINATOR_STRATEGY JavaDocs for additional details.
>
> The following short-names are recognized: jdbc::(the default for non-JPA applications) says to use JDBC-based transactions (org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl) jta::says to use JTA-based transactions (org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2015-November/013625.html, instead of

```
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
```

try this

```
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl</property>
```

Comment: the new property name in Hibernate 5 must be "hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class" instead of "hibernate.transaction.factory_class". See my update here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43264720/2200690